# Teamcity ignores changes in different branches of mercurial

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I am trying to make my team-city build configuration to trigger a build upon any new tag in any branch of my mercurial repository.
I added a build triggering as follows:

```
+:/.hgtags
-:.
```

My problem is that team-city detects changes in the .hgtags only for the current tip branch.
If someone pushes a new tag to another branch, team-city doesn't seem to detect this change in .hgtags (because it was not changes in the current tag) and doesn't trigger a new build.

How can I overcome this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TeamCity Mercurial](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Mercurial) page

> Starting with TeamCity 7.1 you can configure the branches you want to
> monitor in a build configurations right in the VCS root:
>
> **Branch Specification**  In this area list all the branches you want to be
> monitored for changes. The syntax is similar to checkout rules:
> +|-:branch_name ... (with optional * placeholder). Note that only one asterisk is allowed, and each rule has to start with a new line.

Comment: Thanks. Besides the fact that my company currently uses TC 7.0.3, I don't want to limit my build to specific branches, but rather make it look on a certain file across **all** branches.

Comment: @amitfr - `+:*` *will be* **"all branches"**